# Getting CORS response from server but only for one api call out of two

Tags: javascript, ajax

**Summery of the problem:**

I am stuck in a strange issue where I am making two calls to the same API, one gets successful and another is returning `504`.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://ocr.mywebsite.ai/tesseract/basic/' from origin
>   'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

---

**Detailed Problem**

I have one api which accepts image as `blob` and responds with parsed json. I have two images, so I call the api twice using Promise.all() as follows:

```
let ocrPromises = id_card_images.map((image, index) => {
                let header: IHeadersData = {};
                header = index === 0 ? {card_side: "front"} : {card_side: "back"};
                return this.parseImageUsingOCR(image, header)//makes http call and return promise
            });
let ocrData = await Promise.all(ocrPromises);
```

One of these requests gives back `200` response right away while another one fails after above 5 sec with code `504`. Could anyone suggest what could be the possible reason for such behavior?

Following the chrome network panel. First is failed request second is passed request.
[image: failed Request]
[image: passed Request]

---

**parseImageUsingOCR** method which makes actual server call (this is a bit of angular 7 code)

```
parseImageUsingOCR(image, header: IHeadersData): Promise<{ parsed_data: any, s3_url: string }> {


        let blob = UtilityService.dataURItoBlob(image);
        let transliterationUrl = ConstantService.getTransliterationUrl();
        let formData: FormData = new FormData();
        formData.append('image', blob);
        let userData = StoreService.getUserData();
        let transliterationHeader: IHeadersData = UtilityService.getHeaderForOCRParseByCountryAndIdType(
            userData.country,
            userData.id_card_type
        );
        transliterationHeader = {
            ...transliterationHeader,
            img_type: 'id_card',
            ...header,
            // "content-type": "application/json"
        };

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            // alert(JSON.stringify(transliterationHeader));
            this.serverService.makePostRequest({url: transliterationUrl, body: formData, header: transliterationHeader})
                .subscribe((val: { parsed_data: IUser, raw_data: string, s3_url: string }) => {
                    if (val.parsed_data) {
                        resolve({
                            parsed_data: this.removeAllUndefinedFieldsFromObject(val.parsed_data),
                            s3_url: val.s3_url
                        })
                    } else {
                        resolve({parsed_data: {}, s3_url: val.s3_url});
                    }
                })
        })
    }
```

Comment: Can you also post the code for parsingImageUsingOCR method?

Comment: I added that. Thanks

Comment: Does your server use another service to parse your images? I think this might be something you want to check also on your server because the 504 code is a [`Gateway Timeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/504)

Comment: Since you have one successful request that's also a hint that this is more likely a backend issue.

Comment: Yes the backend is using some amazon service. But why would that be causing timeout?

Comment: How about proxies? Are you using any proxy server locally or on your server?

Comment: can't comment on that since I dont manage backend. Will let you know asap.

Answer (score 6):

This isn't really a CORS problem.

The request that gets a 200 OK response shows the CORS header is present.
The failing request isn't being answered from whatever server is supposed to answer, so a gateway in between that server and you is returning a Gateway timeout (HTTP 504).

This is a problem anyway and the fact that the gateway server isn't sending a CORS header wouldn't make much of a difference. I suspect that the OCR server took too long to respond and the gateway cancelled the request and responded with a timeout instead.

Either increase the gateway timeout setting or try with smaller images which hopefully won't take the OCR too long to process.

Comment: Seems correct to me thanks. Had a web server behind an AWS Load Balancer with a default idle timeout of 60 seconds and the request was indeed taking ~1.4 min. Increasing the timeout fixed it